# Python converting yyyy-mm-dd to dd/mm/yyyy but still keep the column as a date type in excel

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

Im working with a dataset with numerous date columns in yyyy-mm-dd format. Is it possible to change this to dd/mm/yyyy format while still keeping the column classed as date and not change it to a string format?

Comment: No, not possible in `python/pandas`

Comment: it's not possible to manipulate the number format in excel from pandas if that is what you ask

Comment: That has made me really sad @jezrael